# Kafka on Kubernetes with SSL

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, apache-kafka, external, kubernetes-ingress

I have a Kafka cluster that is running on K8S. I am using the confluent kafka image as and I have an EXTERNAL listeners that is working.
How can I add SSL encryption? Should I use an ingress? Where can I find good documentation?
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend using Strimzi kafka operator to deploy Kafka to Kubernetes. I'm using it in production for a year now.
It supports SSL, external load balancers, kafka exporter, etc
[Strimzi Kafka Operator](https://strimzi.io/docs/overview/latest/)

Answer (score 5):

You have a [manual way in this gist](https://gist.github.com/aramalipoor/f62355cd440584986bfd91bd69e52c49#file-0-readme-md), which does not use the confluent image.

But for [Confluent and its Helm chart](https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-helm-charts) (see "[Confluent Operator: Getting Started with Apache Kafka and Kubernetes](https://www.confluent.io/blog/getting-started-apache-kafka-kubernetes/)" from [Rohit Bakhshi](https://twitter.com/rohit2b)), you can follow:

"[Encryption, authentication and external access for Confluent Kafka on Kubernetes](https://medium.com/weareservian/encryption-authentication-and-external-access-for-confluent-kafka-on-kubernetes-69c723a612fc)" from [Ryan Morris](https://github.com/ryan-c-m)

> Out of the box, the helm chart doesn’t support SSL configurations for encryption and authentication, or exposing the platform for access from outside the Kubernetes cluster.
>
> To implement these requirements, there are a few modifications to the installation needed.
>   In summary, they are:
>
> - Generate some private keys/certificates for brokers and clients
> - Create Kubernetes Secrets to provide them within your cluster
> - Update the broker StatefulSet with your Secrets and SSL configuration
> - Expose each broker pod via an external service